# How to get text content first preceding and following text node in DOM using given xpath?

Tags: java, dom, xpath

I have a DOM say:

```
<div>
    <span>
    Create Account
    </span>

    <label>Enter first name </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName"> First name
    </input>

    <label>Enter last name </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName"> Last name
    </input>

</div>
```

Now, Suppose I have only Xpath for `id="firstName"` as `//input[@id='firstName']`.
Now if I want to know textContent of the first preceding("Enter first name") and following("Enter last name") text node. 
How I can get that ?

I tried this: `//input[@id='firstName']/preceding::*[text()][1]` similarly `//input[@id='firstName']/following::*[text()][1]`

But they instead give me complete element node, I just want text content.

Comment: `//input[@id='firstName']/preceding::*[text()][1]/text()`

Comment: Or even `//input[@id='firstName']/preceding::label[1]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath to match both text nodes:

```
//label[following-sibling::input[@id='firstName'][1] or preceding-sibling::input[@id='firstName'][1]]/text()
```

Comment: @Om Sao , any feedback?